# Babel warns of lack of hyphenation patterns for Hebrew

Tags: hyphenation, babel, warnings, hebrew

I use TeX Live including the Hebrew package. I've tried to produce a simple TeX file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage [english,hebrew]{babel}
\begin{document}
שלום
\end{document}
```

but I keep getting the infamous

```
Package babel Warning: No hyphenation patterns were loaded for the language `Hebrew'.
```

I've searched all over but can't find the solution.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Is Hebrew hyphenated at all?

Comment: @egreg: it may be hyphenate-able, but not with anything obvious on ctan.  (it's a bit sad, if it _isn't_ hyphenatable, that babel doesn't "know", and throws the warning anyway.)

Comment: @Adam, please consider accepting the answer. Alternatively, if you're getting this and then an error about missing font metrics, see [these](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/87959/5640) two [questions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/113367/5640).

Answer (score 10):

As far as my research in the net has been able to find, hyphenation in Hebrew is used mainly (or even uniquely) in newspaper typeset in narrow columns. There are *no* hyphenation pattern files for Hebrew that I know of; surely not on CTAN.

The message you get is a long standing misfeature of `babel`, which, when it doesn't find hyphenation patterns preloaded for a language, decides arbitrarily to use the patterns for English (`\language0`, to be precise).

You can cure the problem with a hack:

```
\documentclass{article}

% Fool babel
\makeatletter\let\l@hebrew\l@nohyphenation\makeatother

\usepackage [english,hebrew]{babel}
\begin{document}
 שלום
\end{document}
```

`\l@hebrew` is the internal command that `babel` looks for. You have two advantages with this: the message will not appear and you risk *no* wrong application of hyphenation. In my opinion, no hyphenation is better than a wrong one based on the rules for (American) English.

If you still get the message, it means that your TeX distribution doesn't define the `nohyphenation` pseudolanguage. The remedy then is to say

```
\makeatletter\chardef\l@hebrew=255 \makeatother
```

which works unless your TeX distribution defines hyphenation patterns for 256 languages, and this seems unlikely.

Comment: MiKTeX needs definitely your second solution.