# TeX fails to generate output with Hebrew text: Jerusalem font metric file missing

Tags: fonts, errors, miktex, babel, hebrew

I have MiKTeX installed on a Windows machine.

I have this simple document, where I'm trying to use Hebrew:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{ucs}   % package to add unicode support
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}  % adding the UTF-8 encoding
\usepackage[english,hebrew]{babel}
\usepackage{hebfont}
\begin{document}
\sethebrew
Hello world % \textshold{   שלום עולם!}
\end{document}
```

The compiler says to me:

```
Package babel Warning: No hyphenation patterns were loaded for
(babel)                the language `Hebrew'
(babel)                I will use the patterns loaded for \language=0 instead.

)) ("D:\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\lheenc.def")
("D:\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\hebfont.sty") (C:\u1.aux)
("D:\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\babel\lhecmr.fd")
("D:\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\ucs\ucsencs.def")Running miktex-makemf.exe...
miktex-makemf: The jerus source file could not be found.
Running hbf2gf.exe...

hbf2gf (CJK ver. 4.8.0)

Couldn't find `jerus.cfg'
miktex-maketfm: No creation rule for font jerus10.

! Font LHE/cmr/m/n/12=jerus10 at 12.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
```

What is the problem?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Package `babel` does not have hyphenation patterns for hebrew (see [babel warns of lack of hyphenation patterns for hebrew](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85473/babel-warns-of-lack-of-hyphenation-patterns-for-hebrew)), therefore you get the warning. Have you installed hebrew fonts?

Comment: gipc, did none of the answers here resolve the issue?

Answer (score 3):

The lack of hyphenation patterns is not the problem, as [mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85473/babel-warns-of-lack-of-hyphenation-patterns-for-hebrew).

You're most probably missing the appropriate Hebrew fonts. Download and install the Culmus package. If you're using MiKTeX on Windows, get it from [here](http://www.ma.huji.ac.il/~sameti/tex/culmusmiktex.html). If you're on Linux, your distribution should have package(s) with Hebrew support for LaTeX or a specific Culmus package; or you can download [the two ivritex tarballs](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ivritex/files/), one of which includes the Culmus fonts.

Also, it is not necessary to use `\hebfont`; have a look at the [source](http://www.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/macros/latex/exptl/babel-alpha/contrib/hebrew/hebfont.sty) to see what it offers (it's pretty readable even if you're not a LaTeX expert).

If for some reason installing Culmus does not solve the problem, try following the instructions [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/113431/5640); they're for TeXLive but it should probably work for MiKTeX as well.

Comment: Yes; none of the Hebrew fonts is in TeX Live nor, I'm told, in MiKTeX; probably a licensing problem. So one has to install the fonts separately.

Comment: @egreg: I wonder if it's really a licensing problem though. I'm sure the original authors would be glad to license the fonts under different terms. Someone should ask the distro maintainers sometime.

Answer (score 1):

One way to typeset Hebrew using TeX is to use the [Polyglossia](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/polyglossia) package, which requires the `XeLaTeX` engine rather than the usual `LaTeX` or `pdfLaTeX`.

All modern TeX implementations include the `XeLaTeX` program.  To run `XeLaTeX` from the command line, simply type `xelatex` instead of the usual `latex` or `pdflatex`.    If you normally run LaTeX from a button in your text editor, there should be a setting to change it to XeLaTeX.  [Depending on the editor](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/84687), adding the following "TeX directive" to the top of your TeX source file may instruct the editor to use XeLaTeX automatically:

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex
```

(Make sure there is nothing else on the same line, not even a subsequent comment.)

The basic use of Polyglossia is illustrated below, with a document containing English and Hebrew.

Important:  The line `\setotherlanguage{hebrew}` loads the [Bidi](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/bidi) package, and therefore this line must be run after most other packages are loaded, otherwise it will generate a "Package bidi Error".  So if you need any other `\usepackage` lines, make sure to put them before this line.

The font name inserted as the mandatory argument in braces after `\newfontfamily` can be any font on your system containing Hebrew characters.  (In my example, `SBL Hebrew`.)  There must be no extra white-space within the braces before or after the font name (so, for example, `{ SBL Hebrew}` or  `{SBL Hebrew }` won't work).  The optional argument `[Script=Hebrew]` is necessary for the vowels (nekudot) to be placed correctly.

```
% !TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{xltxtra}

\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text, Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfont[Script=Hebrew]{SBL Hebrew}

\begin{document}
This is a regular paragraph in English.

\begin{hebrew}
עכשיו אני כותב קטע שלם בעברית.
\end{hebrew}

Now back to English, the default language.

I will insert some \texthebrew{מלים בעברית} into this sentence.

\begin{hebrew}
עכשיו אני כותב קטע בעברית עם \textenglish{English words} באמצע.

אֶפְשָׁר לִכְתּוֹב גַּם עִם נְקוּדוֹת!
\end{hebrew}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `! TeX` instruction only works with a few editors, cf. [When and why should I use % !TEX TS-program and % !TEX encoding?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/84687)