# Latex returns exit code 1 when I try this very simple code, why?

Tags: hebrew

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,hebrew]{babel}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

This is the .log file, the .aux just says "\relax"

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian) (format=pdflatex 2013.12.2)  2 DEC 2013 10:38
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**Throwme.tex
(./Throwme.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9f> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count79
\c@section=\count80
\c@subsection=\count81
\c@subsubsection=\count82
\c@paragraph=\count83
\c@subparagraph=\count84
\c@figure=\count85
\c@table=\count86
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
Package: inputenc 2008/03/30 v1.1d Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks14
\inpenc@posthook=\toks15

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/utf8.def
File: utf8.def 2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
Now handling font encoding OML ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OML
Now handling font encoding T1 ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding T1

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.dfu
File: t1enc.dfu 2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
   defining Unicode char U+00A1 (decimal 161)
   defining Unicode char U+00A3 (decimal 163)
   defining Unicode char U+00AB (decimal 171)
   defining Unicode char U+00BB (decimal 187)
   defining Unicode char U+00BF (decimal 191)
   defining Unicode char U+00C0 (decimal 192)
   defining Unicode char U+00C1 (decimal 193)
   defining Unicode char U+00C2 (decimal 194)
   defining Unicode char U+00C3 (decimal 195)
   defining Unicode char U+00C4 (decimal 196)
   defining Unicode char U+00C5 (decimal 197)
   defining Unicode char U+00C6 (decimal 198)
   defining Unicode char U+00C7 (decimal 199)
   defining Unicode char U+00C8 (decimal 200)
   defining Unicode char U+00C9 (decimal 201)
   defining Unicode char U+00CA (decimal 202)
   defining Unicode char U+00CB (decimal 203)
   defining Unicode char U+00CC (decimal 204)
   defining Unicode char U+00CD (decimal 205)
   defining Unicode char U+00CE (decimal 206)
   defining Unicode char U+00CF (decimal 207)
   defining Unicode char U+00D0 (decimal 208)
   defining Unicode char U+00D1 (decimal 209)
   defining Unicode char U+00D2 (decimal 210)
   defining Unicode char U+00D3 (decimal 211)
   defining Unicode char U+00D4 (decimal 212)
   defining Unicode char U+00D5 (decimal 213)
   defining Unicode char U+00D6 (decimal 214)
   defining Unicode char U+00D8 (decimal 216)
   defining Unicode char U+00D9 (decimal 217)
   defining Unicode char U+00DA (decimal 218)
   defining Unicode char U+00DB (decimal 219)
   defining Unicode char U+00DC (decimal 220)
   defining Unicode char U+00DD (decimal 221)
   defining Unicode char U+00DE (decimal 222)
   defining Unicode char U+00DF (decimal 223)
   defining Unicode char U+00E0 (decimal 224)
   defining Unicode char U+00E1 (decimal 225)
   defining Unicode char U+00E2 (decimal 226)
   defining Unicode char U+00E3 (decimal 227)
   defining Unicode char U+00E4 (decimal 228)
   defining Unicode char U+00E5 (decimal 229)
   defining Unicode char U+00E6 (decimal 230)
   defining Unicode char U+00E7 (decimal 231)
   defining Unicode char U+00E8 (decimal 232)
   defining Unicode char U+00E9 (decimal 233)
   defining Unicode char U+00EA (decimal 234)
   defining Unicode char U+00EB (decimal 235)
   defining Unicode char U+00EC (decimal 236)
   defining Unicode char U+00ED (decimal 237)
   defining Unicode char U+00EE (decimal 238)
   defining Unicode char U+00EF (decimal 239)
   defining Unicode char U+00F0 (decimal 240)
   defining Unicode char U+00F1 (decimal 241)
   defining Unicode char U+00F2 (decimal 242)
   defining Unicode char U+00F3 (decimal 243)
   defining Unicode char U+00F4 (decimal 244)
   defining Unicode char U+00F5 (decimal 245)
   defining Unicode char U+00F6 (decimal 246)
   defining Unicode char U+00F8 (decimal 248)
   defining Unicode char U+00F9 (decimal 249)
   defining Unicode char U+00FA (decimal 250)
   defining Unicode char U+00FB (decimal 251)
   defining Unicode char U+00FC (decimal 252)
   defining Unicode char U+00FD (decimal 253)
   defining Unicode char U+00FE (decimal 254)
   defining Unicode char U+00FF (decimal 255)
   defining Unicode char U+0102 (decimal 258)
   defining Unicode char U+0103 (decimal 259)
   defining Unicode char U+0104 (decimal 260)
   defining Unicode char U+0105 (decimal 261)
   defining Unicode char U+0106 (decimal 262)
   defining Unicode char U+0107 (decimal 263)
   defining Unicode char U+010C (decimal 268)
   defining Unicode char U+010D (decimal 269)
   defining Unicode char U+010E (decimal 270)
   defining Unicode char U+010F (decimal 271)
   defining Unicode char U+0110 (decimal 272)
   defining Unicode char U+0111 (decimal 273)
   defining Unicode char U+0118 (decimal 280)
   defining Unicode char U+0119 (decimal 281)
   defining Unicode char U+011A (decimal 282)
   defining Unicode char U+011B (decimal 283)
   defining Unicode char U+011E (decimal 286)
   defining Unicode char U+011F (decimal 287)
   defining Unicode char U+0130 (decimal 304)
   defining Unicode char U+0131 (decimal 305)
   defining Unicode char U+0132 (decimal 306)
   defining Unicode char U+0133 (decimal 307)
   defining Unicode char U+0139 (decimal 313)
   defining Unicode char U+013A (decimal 314)
   defining Unicode char U+013D (decimal 317)
   defining Unicode char U+013E (decimal 318)
   defining Unicode char U+0141 (decimal 321)
   defining Unicode char U+0142 (decimal 322)
   defining Unicode char U+0143 (decimal 323)
   defining Unicode char U+0144 (decimal 324)
   defining Unicode char U+0147 (decimal 327)
   defining Unicode char U+0148 (decimal 328)
   defining Unicode char U+014A (decimal 330)
   defining Unicode char U+014B (decimal 331)
   defining Unicode char U+0150 (decimal 336)
   defining Unicode char U+0151 (decimal 337)
   defining Unicode char U+0152 (decimal 338)
   defining Unicode char U+0153 (decimal 339)
   defining Unicode char U+0154 (decimal 340)
   defining Unicode char U+0155 (decimal 341)
   defining Unicode char U+0158 (decimal 344)
   defining Unicode char U+0159 (decimal 345)
   defining Unicode char U+015A (decimal 346)
   defining Unicode char U+015B (decimal 347)
   defining Unicode char U+015E (decimal 350)
   defining Unicode char U+015F (decimal 351)
   defining Unicode char U+0160 (decimal 352)
   defining Unicode char U+0161 (decimal 353)
   defining Unicode char U+0162 (decimal 354)
   defining Unicode char U+0163 (decimal 355)
   defining Unicode char U+0164 (decimal 356)
   defining Unicode char U+0165 (decimal 357)
   defining Unicode char U+016E (decimal 366)
   defining Unicode char U+016F (decimal 367)
   defining Unicode char U+0170 (decimal 368)
   defining Unicode char U+0171 (decimal 369)
   defining Unicode char U+0178 (decimal 376)
   defining Unicode char U+0179 (decimal 377)
   defining Unicode char U+017A (decimal 378)
   defining Unicode char U+017B (decimal 379)
   defining Unicode char U+017C (decimal 380)
   defining Unicode char U+017D (decimal 381)
   defining Unicode char U+017E (decimal 382)
   defining Unicode char U+200C (decimal 8204)
   defining Unicode char U+2013 (decimal 8211)
   defining Unicode char U+2014 (decimal 8212)
   defining Unicode char U+2018 (decimal 8216)
   defining Unicode char U+2019 (decimal 8217)
   defining Unicode char U+201A (decimal 8218)
   defining Unicode char U+201C (decimal 8220)
   defining Unicode char U+201D (decimal 8221)
   defining Unicode char U+201E (decimal 8222)
   defining Unicode char U+2030 (decimal 8240)
   defining Unicode char U+2031 (decimal 8241)
   defining Unicode char U+2039 (decimal 8249)
   defining Unicode char U+203A (decimal 8250)
   defining Unicode char U+2423 (decimal 9251)
)
Now handling font encoding OT1 ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OT1

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ot1enc.dfu
File: ot1enc.dfu 2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
   defining Unicode char U+00A1 (decimal 161)
   defining Unicode char U+00A3 (decimal 163)
   defining Unicode char U+00B8 (decimal 184)
   defining Unicode char U+00BF (decimal 191)
   defining Unicode char U+00C5 (decimal 197)
   defining Unicode char U+00C6 (decimal 198)
   defining Unicode char U+00D8 (decimal 216)
   defining Unicode char U+00DF (decimal 223)
   defining Unicode char U+00E6 (decimal 230)
   defining Unicode char U+00EC (decimal 236)
   defining Unicode char U+00ED (decimal 237)
   defining Unicode char U+00EE (decimal 238)
   defining Unicode char U+00EF (decimal 239)
   defining Unicode char U+00F8 (decimal 248)
   defining Unicode char U+0131 (decimal 305)
   defining Unicode char U+0141 (decimal 321)
   defining Unicode char U+0142 (decimal 322)
   defining Unicode char U+0152 (decimal 338)
   defining Unicode char U+0153 (decimal 339)
   defining Unicode char U+2013 (decimal 8211)
   defining Unicode char U+2014 (decimal 8212)
   defining Unicode char U+2018 (decimal 8216)
   defining Unicode char U+2019 (decimal 8217)
   defining Unicode char U+201C (decimal 8220)
   defining Unicode char U+201D (decimal 8221)
)
Now handling font encoding OMS ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OMS

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omsenc.dfu
File: omsenc.dfu 2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
   defining Unicode char U+00A7 (decimal 167)
   defining Unicode char U+00B6 (decimal 182)
   defining Unicode char U+00B7 (decimal 183)
   defining Unicode char U+2020 (decimal 8224)
   defining Unicode char U+2021 (decimal 8225)
   defining Unicode char U+2022 (decimal 8226)
)
Now handling font encoding OMX ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OMX
Now handling font encoding U ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding U
   defining Unicode char U+00A9 (decimal 169)
   defining Unicode char U+00AA (decimal 170)
   defining Unicode char U+00AE (decimal 174)
   defining Unicode char U+00BA (decimal 186)
   defining Unicode char U+02C6 (decimal 710)
   defining Unicode char U+02DC (decimal 732)
   defining Unicode char U+200C (decimal 8204)
   defining Unicode char U+2026 (decimal 8230)
   defining Unicode char U+2122 (decimal 8482)
   defining Unicode char U+2423 (decimal 9251)
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
Package: babel 2013/05/16 v3.9f The Babel package

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-english/english.ldf
Language: english 2012/08/20 v3.3p English support from the babel system

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def
File: babel.def 2013/05/16 v3.9f Babel common definitions
\babel@savecnt=\count87
\U@D=\dimen103
)
\l@canadian = a dialect from \language\l@american 
\l@australian = a dialect from \language\l@british 
\l@newzealand = a dialect from \language\l@british 
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-hebrew/rlbabel.def
File: rlbabel.def 2005/03/30 v2.3h Right-to-Left support from the babel system 
Hebrew language support from the babel system
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-hebrew/hebrew.ldf
File: hebrew.ldf 2005/03/30 v2.3h Hebrew language definition from the babel sys
tem Hebrew language support from the babel system


Package babel Warning: No hyphenation patterns were preloaded for
(babel)                the language `Hebrew' into the format.
(babel)                Please, configure your TeX system to add them and
(babel)                rebuild the format. Now I will use the patterns
(babel)                preloaded for english instead on input line 57.

\l@hebrew = a dialect from \language0
)) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-hebrew/lheenc.def
File: lheenc.def 2005/05/20 v1.2c 7-bit Hebrew font encoding (test version: sti
ll liable to change)
Now handling font encoding LHE ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding LHE
)
No file Throwme.aux.
\openout1 = `Throwme.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for LHE/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for LHE+cmr on input line 4.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-hebrew/lhecmr.fd
File: lhecmr.fd 2005/05/20 v1.2c Hebrew default font (test version: still liabl
e to change)
)
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 4.

! Font LHE/cmr/m/n/10=jerus10 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not fou
nd.
<to be read again> 
                   relax 
l.4 \begin{document}

I wasn't able to read the size data for this font,
so I will ignore the font specification.
[Wizards can fix TFM files using TFtoPL/PLtoTF.]
You might try inserting a different font spec;
e.g., type `I\font<same font id>=<substitute font name>'.

(./Throwme.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 1042 strings out of 493307
 11870 string characters out of 6139905
 68160 words of memory out of 5000000
 4545 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 957 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 24i,1n,23p,169b,43s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

No pages of output.
PDF statistics:
 0 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/138992/help-getting-started-with-hebrew-in-babel

Comment: You have only one error. The font file `jerus10.tfm` cannot be found. If that file exists, and lies somewhere under `fonts/tfm/` in a texmf directory, then perhaps you forgot to run `mktexlsr`. If that file does not exist, the font needs to be properly installed.

Comment: Since one error is raised, the exit code is 1.

Answer (score 0):

Considering how the problem is the lack of the Jerusalem font metric file, your question is similar to

[TeX fails to generate output with Hebrew text: Jerusalem font metric file missing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/87959/5640)

So I'll refer you to my [answer there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/88004/5640).

Also, many people recommend using utf8x for Hebrew; see [my (completely different) answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/29247/5640) on that matter.