# The picture of tikz is not shown

Tags: tikz-pgf, lyx

I am new to the pgf package ant I wrote that code but when I compiled it (successfully), the picture was not shown.

The code:

```
%% LyX 2.1.2 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[11pt,english,hebrew]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[cp1255]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2cm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0bp}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{enumitem}       % customizable list environments
\newlength{\lyxlabelwidth}      % auxiliary length 

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}

\title{����������}

\maketitle
������

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[fill=yellow] (0,0) -- (60:.75cm) arc (60:180:.75cm);
    \draw(120:0.4cm) node {$\alpha$};

    \draw[fill=green!30] (0,0) -- (right:.75cm) arc (0:60:.75cm);
    \draw(30:0.5cm) node {$\beta$};

    \begin{scope}[shift={(60:2cm)}]
        \draw[fill=green!30] (0,0) -- (180:.75cm) arc (180:240:.75cm);
        \draw (30:-0.5cm) node {$\gamma$};

        \draw[fill=yellow] (0,0) -- (240:.75cm) arc (240:360:.75cm);
        \draw (-60:0.4cm) node {$\delta$};
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}[thick]
        \draw (60:-1cm) node[fill=white] {$E$} -- (60:3cm) node[fill=white] {$F$};
        \draw[red] (-2,0) node[left] {$A$} -- (3,0) node[right]{$B$};
        \draw[blue,shift={(60:2cm)}] (-3,0) node[left] {$C$} -- (2,0) node[right]{$D$};

        \draw[shift={(60:1cm)},xshift=4cm]
        node [right,text width=6cm,rounded corners,fill=red!20,inner sep=1ex]
        {
            When we assume that $\color{red}AB$ and $\color{blue}CD$ are
            parallel, i.\,e., ${\color{red}AB} \mathbin{\|} \color{blue}CD$,
            then $\alpha = \delta$ and $\beta = \gamma$.
        };
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: If I remove the hebrew code, I get the picture... But I don't have hebrew support installed, so I can't compile your example with it.

Comment: you are correct. it does works without the hebrew. interesting why is does not work. thanks!

Comment: here is the solution for the problen (add \L before you start the tikz code) http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/167167/tikz-and-babel-disagree-when-hebrew-is-loaded