# Can't compile Hebrew LyX (2.3) files since the new Miktex 2.9

Tags: fonts, errors, lyx, hebrew

I have recently installed LyX 2.3.1-1 on a fresh PC running Windows 10 Pro (64bit), following the instructions here:
https://wiki.lyx.org/Windows/Hebrew

I have installed the latest Miktex 2.9 (dated October 4th 2018, and I suspect this is relevant), and culmus 0.2.2 as per the instructions above.
The culmus installation does not report errors, and yet after following through with the instructions, when I try to compile the simplest .lyx file (a Hebrew article with the text "שלום עולם") I get the following error:

> Font LHE/cmr/m/n/12=jerus10 at 12.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found

This error has many threads about it, for instance [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87959/tex-fails-to-generate-output-with-hebrew-text-jerusalem-font-metric-file-missin), however none of the suggestions I've found seem to work. I suspect something in the inner workings of Miktex has changed and the culmus installation does not copy the files to the correct place; at least, if I try to trace back where the files should be located according to the files the culmus installation deletes before installing, I don't find anything at all. I tried copying a few key font files to where I think they should be located, but that didn't work, at which point I thought of asking whether someone has encountered this issue and succeeded in solving it.

Comment: I didn't check the exe but the organization of the zip-file looks okay. Your error about LHE seems to indicate that you have some older culmus version around. But also the new version is without changes no longer usable in a modern tex system, e.g. support for utf8 is missing. Contact the author.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've installed all of the Hebrew packages I could find on the Miktex Console (the `datetime2-hebrew` package was missing), added `\usepackage{culmus}` to the document's preampble, and the file compiled. I'm not sure which of the two steps was the key, I think it was the latter.

(I came across this solution on a LyX Hebrew facebook group, it also appears [here](https://www.guyrutenberg.com/culmus-latex/))

Edit: Following up on @KJO's suggestion, I copied the example from the linked page into a .tex file and tried to compile it. This actually didn't work as is, I need to add `\usepackage{culmus}`.

Anyways, the following code works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage{culmus}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,hebrew]{babel}
\begin{document} 
שלום \L{World}!
\end{document}
```

Here's a proof:
[image: Proof that the code works]

Comment: I would cut and paste the "examples" hello world example on that page into a .tex file (to prove it works) then paste it as "code" into your answer with a cliped image as proof for others that it "works" then accept your own answer