# How to use hebrew in latex - font or installation errors

Tags: pdftex, texlive, ubuntu, hebrew

I am trying to get latex working with hebrew and english using ubuntu 14.04 and TeX Live 2013/Debian.  The following fails to run due to:

```
! I can't find file `jerus10'.
```

The input file is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hebrew]{babel}
\begin{document}

hello or שלום
 \L{World}!

\end{document}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as it seems most docs on the web are very old.

(suggestions to use lyx, elatex, etc. are not really helpful as they are not solutions to the problem.  Thank you in advance)

Comment: Hi and welcome, the easiest solution would be to use XeLaTeX ;-) [How do I add Hebrew support to TeXLive on Windows (with pdfTeX+babel)?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/113367) The link deals with Windows, but it's basically the same on Linux. But make sure to copy the files in your texmfHOME dir.

Comment: Actually, I don't think the post you mention works very well.  Many of the links are dead, some of the repos it mentions are more than 6 years old.  I am hoping to see a solution that is more modern, has a chance of success, and is native to latex.  I will help with the solution, but starting from that post is not particularly useful.

Comment: The thing that bothers me is, that for some reason, the fonts aren't properly installed via the package manager. `hebrew.sty` dates back to 2003, where XeLaTeX wasn't born yet. It requires files the user has to get by hand. This really bugs me, somebody should have a closer look at this and do something.

Comment: I agree.  There are plenty of suggestions, but all require picking out pieces of old (and no longer maintained) packages, or using something different than latex, or for different operating systems.  I am happy to help put together something new, but need guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out to be easier than expected.  While the documentation is out of date, the solution is easy.

- install texlive-lang-hebrew and texlive-lang-other
- install the culmus-latex as per instructions (I used version 0.7, e.g., http://sourceforge.net/projects/ivritex/files/culmus-latex/culmus-latex-0.7/culmus-latex-0.7-r1.tar.gz/download)

After that everything worked for me on ubuntu 14.04 with texlive 2013.

Comment: What instructions did you have in mind in writing "install the culmus-latex as per instructions"?

Comment: The README in the tar file has installation instructions.

Comment: I find the culmus README instructions unclear, but I have found a work-around. Following [LyX's suggestion](http://wiki.lyx.org/LyX/HebrewOnLinux) I have downloaded [install-tl-ubuntu](https://github.com/scottkosty/install-tl-ubuntu) and ran it as indicated in the LyX link above. I then [switched my TeX processor](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/7128/how-to-determine-the-auctex-tex-engine) to XeTex, and [used the polyglossia package](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/7134/4084).

Comment: Is this for linux only? because i cannot open any file. not even the readme. Is there a windows version? thanks!

Comment: I am on Ubuntu 16.04. There is no package named texlive-lang-hebrew...