# Single hebrew word in english paragraph (babel/pdflatex)

Tags: pdftex, babel, hebrew

How to include a single hebrew word in an english paragraph using babel and pdflatex? I don't want a new paragraph or start from the right when switching to hebrew. If possible, I would like to continue using pdflatex and babel.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hebrew,english]{babel}


\begin{document}

hello world גופן ברירת מחדל hello again

\end{document}
```

Is there any hack/solution? Thank you very much.

Comment: Neither `pdftex` nor `xetex` switch the writing direction automatically and it must be marked explicitly up (or resort to `luatex`). And even so, `hebrew`is somewhat problematic because you must install a separate package - see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113367/how-do-i-add-hebrew-support-to-texlive-on-windows-with-pdftexbabel/113385 .

Comment: See also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/468920/61644 (which doesn't work for me).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory, it’s possible to get something like your set-up to work.  In practice, [even the last maintainer of that package says](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/458342/61644) to switch to XeTeX and `polyglossia`.

In that package, the command is `\texthebrew`.  Example:

```
\documentclass[varwidth=10cm, preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{hebrew}

%\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchUppercase, Ligatures = TeX }

\newfontfamily\hebrewfont{Frank Ruehl CLM}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfontsf{Simple CLM}
\newfontfamily\hebrewfonttt{Miriam Mono CLM}

\begin{document}
hello world \texthebrew{גופן ברירת מחדל} hello again
\end{document}
```

[image: Hello, world?]

It is also possible to get Hebrew to work with `babel` by loading `\babelprovide[import]{hebrew}` and then a command such as `\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}{Frank Ruehl CLM}`.  If some package you need is incompatible with `polyglossia`, that might work better for you.

Comment: alright, apparently switching seems to be the only practical thing. The only drawback is there are still some incompatibilities of packages with xelatex/polyglossia that worked with pdflatex.

Comment: @kromuchi Admittedly, I haven’t been able to get Hebrew to work the way I want in PDFTeX, but in theory there should be packages floating around to do it.

Comment: @kromuchi Which packages are you having problems with? There might be a fix or a replacement for them.

Comment: In general, a few packages need different options or the order is important. Currently, the most challenging thing is to find a compatible version of polyglossia/bidi and koma script (with the current versions, some commands don't work (I created a ticket on sourceforge which is now also linked here: https://github.com/bidi-tex/bidi/issues/1)

Comment: You can also get Babel to work with Hebrew by loading `\babelprovide[import]{hebrew}` and then selecting a `\babelfont`. If the problem is Pollyglossia, that might work for you.