# Font LHE/cmr/m/n/10=jerus10 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not fou nd

Tags: miktex, hebrew, culmus

I'm trying to compile a mixed English and Hebrew document.
When I try to compile (using WinEDT btw) I get an error massage saying-

```
Sorry, but miktex-makemf did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:\Users\Lea\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\miktex-makemf.log
Running miktex-hbf2gf.exe...

hbf2gf (CJK ver. 4.8.4)

Couldn't open `jerus.cfg'

Sorry, but miktex-maketfm did not succeed.

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:\Users\Lea\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\miktex-maketfm.log

! Font LHE/cmr/m/n/10=jerus10 at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not fou
nd.
<to be read again> 
                   relax 
l.6 \select@language{hebrew}
```

I'm using WinEDT, MIKTeX 2.9, culmus is installed.
Things Iv'e tried:

1. running updmap --admin from the command prompt.
2. running updmap --force from the command prompt.
3. updating MIKTeX.
4. uninstalling and re-installing MIKTeX.

My code is something like

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ucs}   
\usepackage[hebrew,english]{babel}
\usepackage{hebfont}  
\usepackage{culmus}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm, top=3cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{textcomp,gensymb}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{multirow}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\fancyhf{}
\rhead{\emph{Writer's name}}
\lhead{\emph{Title}}
\rfoot{Page \thepage}

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{Affiliation}\par\vspace{1cm}
    {\LARGE Institute name \par}
    \vspace{1cm}
    {\LARGE Academic department \par}
    \vspace{1cm}
    {\Large Bla Bla Bla\par}
    \vspace{1.5cm}
    \selectlanguage{hebrew}
    {\huge\bfseriesטקסט בעברית\par}
    \vspace{2cm}
    \selectlanguage{english}
    {\huge\bfseries Research Titlel\par}
    \vspace{2cm}
    {\Large\itshape Writer's Name\par}
    \vfill
    Advisor: by\par
    Prof.~Advisor \textsc{Surname}
    \vfill
% Bottom of the page
    {\large\today\par}
\end{titlepage}
```

Comment: culmus is either not installed, not up-to-date or you are not using it correctly. Be aware that even with culmus not everything works as it eg doesn't contain suitable  utf8 support.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, i think culmus is installed properly. Hebrew worked ok prior to MIKTeX update. Iv'e also downloaded it again today and re-installed it. Didn't work.

Answer (score 3):

You should add `\usepackage{culmus}` otherwise it tries to load the old ivritex font (Jerusalem, etc.).

Alternatively, switch to xetex, things work match better there. See this [example](https://www.guyrutenberg.com/2015/03/20/hebrew-with-xetex-example/).

I'm advocating xetex even though i maintained [culmus-latex](https://www.guyrutenberg.com/culmus-latex/)

Comment: Hi Guy, culmus is already loaded. Switching to xetex also didn't work.

Comment: Have you specified a Hebrew font for Xetex other than the default?

Comment: No I did not. I think somethink is wrong with culmus/miktex installation but I can't figure out what is it